# Bounding error for a generalized continued fraction partial sum

Tags: continued-fractions

For a regular continued fraction that converges to $\alpha $ we have $\vert \alpha - \frac {A_n}{B_n} \vert < \frac {A_n}{B_n^2}$. Is there a similar result for generalized continued fractions? I need to estimate the accuracy of my $ \frac {A_n}{B_n} $, and faiked to find a similar result.

Comment: A better estimate is $\left|\,\alpha-\frac{A_n}{B_n}\,\right|\lt\frac1{B_n^2}$ for regular continued fractions. However, I don't know of estimates for generalized continued fractions.